# memcpy always copy the value even without calling it for the second time?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm having problems using `memcpy()`.
I wanted to copy the  value of array `v` to `oldv` only one time, and then change the value of `v`.
I called `memcpy()` in the first part of code and it did what it should do, but in the second part when I changed the array `v` and then print again the `v` and `oldv` ...without calling `memcpy()` for the second time, the value of `oldv` changed too. Why ? The compiler copied the new `v` to `oldv` without calling `memcpy()`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    double **v,**oldv;

    v = new double*[3];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++)
        v[i] = new double[2];

    oldv = new double*[3];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++)
        oldv[i] = new double[2];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<2; j++) 
            v[i][j] = i+j;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&oldv[i], &v[i], sizeof(v[0]));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "=================== cpytab ================" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++) 
            cout << oldv[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<2; j++) 
            v[i][j] = 2*(i+j);
    }

    cout << "==================value changed=============" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++) 
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "====================cpytableau==============" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++) 
            cout << oldv[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(unsigned int j=0;j<2;j++)
        delete[] v[j];

    delete[] v;

    for(unsigned int j=0;j<2;j++) 
        delete[] oldv[j];

    delete[] oldv;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked. I converted it to an answer so you can accept it. :) (I wasn't sure if it will solve the problem, so I wrote it as a comment first.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `memcpy` is wrong:

```
memcpy(&oldv[i], &v[i], sizeof(v[0]));
```

Here you copy the **pointers**, not the **array** contents. For the array contents, remove `&` and provide the runtime-known size of the array. (You apply sizeof to a pointer, which gives you the size of, well, the pointer, not the array it points to, which can't be queried using sizeof).

So try:

```
memcpy(oldv[i], v[i], 2 * sizeof(v[0][0]));
```

---

If this wasn't a programming assignment or exercise, consider using `std::vector` in the future.